# Unable to connect to my SQL Server (Error 0)

Tags: sql-server, database-administration, sql-server-express

I am trying to connect to SQL Server using Management Studio, with `'sa'` user, but I get this error:

> A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process. (provider: Shared Memory Provider, error: 0 - No process is on the other end of the pipe.) (Framework Microsoft SqlClient Data Provider)

I tried:

- Restart SQL Server services
- Enable protocols Shared Memory, Named Pipes and TCP/IP
- Successfully connecting with Windows authentication

Nothing is working.

How can I fix the error?

Comment: You should ask this at [dba.se]

Comment: What is the connection string you're using to try and connect?

Comment: macr_s, hi, I am trying to connect with 'connect object explorer' in SQL server express.

Comment: Did you just install SQL Server? When you installed it did you remember to enable "SQL Server and Windows Authentication"?